# SSIS: Delete everything to left of a character in a string

Tags: string, ssis

Note: this is SSIS not sql server

I am pulling data from a file and some columns have names like this:

```
1;&count chocula
13;&roger ramjet
123;&mary smith
45678;&john adams
```

How do I remove the ampersand and everything to the left of it?
I am using the fx transformation for the character.
I thought about finding the character position  for the ampersand and then deleting everthing from start to that position but ssis does not have that function.  The ampersand can be at any position, I cannot say it is guaranteed to be in position such and such.

Thanks

Comment: Use FINDSTRING to get the position of the &                                           
Then use a RIGHT (or substring for old versions) to remove everything before the &

Something like (not tested): RIGHT([yourcolumn], LEN([yourcolumn]) - FINDSTRING([yourcolumn],"&",1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RIGHT() function retrieves the last X characters of a string.

```
RIGHT("13;&roger ramjet",12)                                      = roger ramjet
```

Above, X equals 12.  Of course, twelve won't work for every string.  Instead we can calculate X by subtracting the string length from the position of the ampersand.

```
LEN(MyColumn])                                                    = 16
FINDSTRING([MyColumn],"&",1)                                      = 4
```

Or put another way...

```
RIGHT([MyColumn], LEN([MyColumn]) - FINDSTRING([MyColumn],"&",1)) = roger ramjet
```

Comment: I forgot to post the answer here.  Thanks for all the assistance Troy.  This worked for me:  REPLACE([MyColumn],SUBSTRING(MyColumn,1,FINDSTRING(MyColumn,"#",1)),"")

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for coming back and check marking!  Glad you got it sorted!